# Concatenate several files in directory with a prepend and append file

Tags: bash, command-line, cat

I have a directory of files that need two files merged to each one.
For simplicity, let's use `intro.txt` and `outro.txt`.

So, for files `file1.txt` to `file3.txt` I would like new files that contain

- `intro.txt` + `file1.txt` + `outro.txt`
- `intro.txt` + `file2.txt` + `outro.txt`
- `intro.txt` + `file3.txt` + `outro.txt`

respectively.

For a single file I would do

```
cat intro.txt file1.txt outro.txt > output.txt
```

How can I best accomplish this for many files?

Comment: Where does the result go? Back into `file1.txt` and so on?

Comment: Is there a common naming scheme for the "meat" files (`file1.txt` ... `file3.txt` in your example), or do you take the filenames from a file? Can you show us what you already tried, and where you faced problems?

Comment: Yes, the text is just merged into file1 (optionally having it dump out a new file name is acceptable) - I haven't really tried anything, because not sure where to start honestly.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the body files, use `cat` to concatenate the header and footer files with each body file, output to a new name:

```bsh
for body in file*.txt; do
    cat intro.txt "$body" outro.txt >"${body%.txt}-complete.txt"
done
```

This writes the completed files to names like `file1-complete.txt`, `file2-complete.txt`.  The output filename is constructed by removing the known `.txt` filename suffix from the name in `$body` and attaching `-complete.txt` at the end.

Note that any already existing output files are overwritten.

Comment: ... have you turned into a mind-reader? ;)

Comment: @AdminBee There's only so many ways this could be done :-)  Yours is a `bash`/`zsh` solution though, while I tend to keep to `sh`.

Comment: You're right, of course, but the timing makes it somewhat spooky ;)

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that the names of your "meat" files (you called them `file1.txt` to `file3.txt`) are such that it can be covered by a glob expression, such as `file*.txt`.

In that case, the following should work (I am assuming Bash-style string operations here, but adapting to other shells should be trivial):

```bash
for f in file*.txt; do
    out="${f/%.txt/_complete.txt}";
    cat intro.txt "$f" outro.txt > "$out";
done
```

This will loop over all files that match the glob expression `file*.txt` and create a new filename, stored in a shell variable `$out`, by replacing the `.txt` suffix with `_complete.txt` (so `file1.txt` would become `file1_complete.txt`). It then `cat`s intro, the current input file, and outro into the new file.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
for f (file<1-3>.txt) (cp =(cat intro.txt - outro.txt) $f) < $f
```

`=(cat intro.txt - outro.txt)` expands to the path of a temporary file containing the output of that `cat` command.

We use redirection instead of `cat intro.txt $f outro.txt` so that the whole `(...)` subshell is cancelled if `$f` can't be open for reading. We use `cp` instead of `mv` so attributes of the file (owner, group, permissions, etc) are preserved.

That would still run `cp` if `cat` failed.

You could instead do it as:

```
for f (file<1-3>.txt) (){
  cat cat intro.txt $f outro.txt > $1 &&
    cp -- $1 $f
} =(:)
```

to avoid it.

`ksh93` has a dedicated redirection operator for this kind of thing:

```
for f in file[123].txt; do
  cat intro.txt "$f" outro.txt >; "$f"
done
```

Where `>;` writes the output to a temporary file which is renamed to the destination if the command succeeded. You may lose some of the original attributes of the file though.

(note that `[123]` matches on either of those 3 characters (`[1-3]` would be more like `[123²¹¼½١٢۱۲߁߂१२১২੧੨૧૨୧୨௧௨౧౨౹౺౼౽೧೨൧൨෧෨๑๒໑໒༡༢༪༫၁၂႑႒፩፪១២៱៲᠑᠒᥇᥈᧑᧒᧚᪁᪂᪑᪒᭑᭒᮱᮲᱁᱂᱑᱒₁₂⅐⅑⅒⅓⅔⅕⅖⅙⅛⅟①②⑩⑪⑫⑬⑭⑮⑯⑰⑱⑲⑳⑴⑵⑽⑾⑿⒀⒁⒂⒃⒄⒅⒆⒇⒈⒉⒑⒒⒓⒔⒕⒖⒗⒘⒙⒚⒛⓫⓬⓭⓮⓯⓰⓱⓲⓳⓴⓵⓶⓾❶❷❿➀➁➉➊➋➓〡〢㉈㉉㉑㉒㉓㉔㉕㉖㉗㉘㉙㋀㋁㋉㋊㋋㍙㍚㍢㍣㍤㍥㍦㍧㍨㍩㍪㍫㍬㍭㍮㍯㍰㏠㏡㏩㏪㏫㏬㏭㏮㏯㏰㏱㏲㏳㏴㏵㏶㏷㏸㏹㏺㏻㏼꘡꘢꣑꣒꤁꤂꧑꧒꧱꧲꩑꩒꯱꯲１２]`) while zsh's `<1-3>` matches on any sequence of decimal digits that make up integers 1 to 3 (so can be extended to any range)).

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in /my/directory/of/files/*; do
    cat /mydir1/prologue.txt "$file" epilogue.txt >>my_file_list
done
```

Comment: Please note your question states "I would like new _files_ that contain ...", whereas your solution appends everything to one single (large) file. And why is `prologue.txt` in a different directory than `epilogue.txt`?

Comment: They aren't an engineer friend replied and this seemed to work, wanted to share.

Answer (score -2):

Make an array of file name in directory, use `cat` to merge multiple files

```
array=($(ls file* | xargs -n 1 basename))
for filename in "${array[@]}"
do
    cat intro.txt $filename outro.txt > final_$filename
done
```

Comment: not sure why you're using `basename` there. As such, it'd just remove the path up to the last `/`, to leave the filename proper there. But with `ls file*`, there shouldn't be any. You could just go with `array=(file*)`. And if you need, you can do prefix/suffix removal on each element of the array with `"${array[@]##*/}"` etc. (Mixing the `ls` and `xargs` there would mess any names with whitespace)

Comment: Please don't iterate over the output of ls, filenames with whitespace will bite you when you least want it. `for $filename in file*; do cat intro.txt "$filename" outro.txt > "final_${filename}"` should be fine (until you hit the shell's expansion limit).

Comment: concat.sh:

#!/bin/bash
array=($(ls file* | xargs -n 1 basename))
for filename in "${array[@]}"
do
    cat prepend.txt "$filename" append.txt > new_$filename
done

CLI $  :

bash concat.sh
ls: cannot access 'file*': No such file or directory
basename: missing operand
Try 'basename --help' for more information.

Comment: The output is the intro/outro txt, but it's not preserving the original text from the document. Every file is the same.